# Is still possion distribution?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have two clients which will submit the job to a server. Let $d$ is number of jobs will submit from the first client and it follows by Poisson distribution as follows:

$$\alpha_d=\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^d}{d!}$$

where $d$ is from $0$ to $n$, and $n$ goes to $+\infty$

While the client 2 only submits one job (d=1) with probability is $p$. Two clients are independent. Which is the distribution of submitting job in the server? Is it still  Poisson distribution?

Comment: 1. If the first client only submits jobs in a range from $1$ to $n$ then the number is not truly Poisson distributed. If it were $0$ to $n$ then most likely you want to say that it is binomial distributed instead (which might be conveniently approximated by a Poisson distribution if $n$ is large). 2. You need to say what the dependence between the two clients is.

Comment: Thank. I will update it again

Comment: In this case it's not Poisson anymore, nor does it have any special name.

Comment: Thank Ian. Because the second client just only submits 1 job to server with probability $p$. Or we can think that after one time unit. Number of 1 job from client 2 will be $Np$. Can we predict distribution of job in server?

Comment: If you sum up a large number of independent Bernoulli(p) random variables (i.e. the number submitted by the second client after a large amount of time), the behavior will eventually be approximately Poisson distributed. Then the sum of independent Poissons is again Poisson, where the means are summed. So in particular, your number of jobs submitted after $N$ time units is approximately Poisson distributed with mean $N(\lambda+p)$, if $N$ is large. How large "large" is depends on what $p$ is.